# Efficiently getting the previous record (by index), in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have an composite index (on 'name' VARCHAR(50) and 'ts' TIMESTAMP columns).

For a particular record, I want to find the preceding record, by time, with the same 'name' (if it exists).

(When using low-level non-relational DBs, such as D-ISAM, this was quick and trivial.)

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: WHERE something is less than something ORDER BY something LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the help I could find was along the lines of @GordonLinoff's answer.

In the end, I solved the problem by adding a 'seq'uence number to each record, showing how far along the index it was.

This is only a solution where the data is append-only, but this is my use case.

I added the values with:

```
SET @num := 0;
UPDATE my_table
SET seq = @num := @num + 1
WHERE name = "my name"
ORDER BY ts, id
```

This worked but is ugly.  It runs in roughly O(n), whereas subquery approaches are O(N^2) which is impractical for anything more than a few thousand rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.  Find all rows that have the same `name` as the record you are looking for.  Then order by `ts` in a reverse order and choose the first one:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select * from table t where <record = your record>
     ) therec
     on t.name = therec.name and t.ts < therec.ts
order by t.ts desc
limit 1;
```